# convert string into datetime format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-conversion

i have a string which, i want to compare with a javascript datetime object.
how to convert string "1/1/1912" into datetime using JavaScript so that i can compare like

```
if (EDateTime > ('1/1/1912'))  {...}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do this simply with a split if you can guarantee the date format.

```
var dateArray = '1/1/1912'.split("/");
new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);
```

Comment: change 
new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);
to
new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1]-1, dateArray[0]);

Answer (score 5):

```
        var dateArray = '2012-02-17 01:10:59'.split(' ');
        var year = dateArray[0].split('-');
        var time = dateArray[1].split(':');

        var finishDate = new Date(year[0], year[1], year[2], time[0], time[1], time[2])
```

Comment: Don't forget to add -1 to year[1] (if this is your month) as month starts from 0 (jan) is javascript.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library?

It can convert `1/1/1912` to `Monday, January 01, 1912 12:00:00 AM` easily

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to `timestamp` with `Date` object.

I found something like:

```
function toTimestamp(year,month,day,hour,minute,second){
   var datum = new Date(Date.UTC(year,month-1,day,hour,minute,second));
   return datum.getTime()/1000;
}
```

`Year`, `month` and `day` parts get with `regular expressions`.

Answer (score 0):

[This library may be helpful.](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/)